# Movie with a woman detective in it and a vampire who falls for her

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

I don't remember the specifics, but after the titles, the opening was about a murder in the streets and a detective was supposed to investigate it.. A man watches her from the roof of one of the nearby buildings.. He falls for her afterwards and so on.. the movie had weird scenes, such as people in a church drinking their own blood and in the last scene a vampire baby is born.

Comment: A good start, but can I suggest you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337) and see if you can add in any more details from the list.

Answer (score 9):

It's a long shot, but this could be the 2007 New Zealand film *[Perfect Creature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_Creature)*.

[image]

> the opening was about a murder in the streets

The first part of the story features an investigation into killings of women in slum

> people in a church drinking their own blood

There are definitely some scenes in a church, and also scenes of people drinking blood - although I can't remember if they are related.

> in the last scene a vampire baby is born

The film ends with the first ever female vampire being born

Comment: That doesn't sound like a long shot at all.

Comment: Well there's not much to go on in the question and it's a fairly obscure film.